# Create a new document from a .dotm template on a weekly basis

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, vba, document-automation

At my workplace, we need to write a report on a weekly basis to document what we have gotten done during that time period.

For that, we have a MS Word template which uses VBA code to fill in date fields, calendar week numbers and other things.
The VBA code is also responsible for dynamically naming the new document (the file name must include the current calendar week) and saving it to a specific folder.

This all works great, except you need to double click the template by hand every monday in order to create a new file for the week which has correctly filled date fields.

Since I am not always at my workplace on  mondays I tried a few things to automate this process, mostly using the task scheduler (ts) that comes with Wiindows 10.

Things I tried:

- Directly executing the template via the ts
- Executing a batch file via the ts which itself calls the template (Note: If I execute that batch file by hand, the new document gets created just fine)
- I thought about writing a service for windows (If that is possible which I think it is) that runs 24/7 and creates a new document every monday at 6 AM but I figured there must be an easier way

Thanks in advance for all ideas.

Cheers

Comment: What issues occured with your use of TaskScheduler?

Comment: @Andy The task doesn't successfully run and under "Last run result" I get "The operator or administrator has refused the request (0x800710E0)". I already allowed the task to run even when the machine isn't on AC power.

Comment: Did the task just attempt to open the document directly, or did it open word with the command line argument to open the document?

Comment: @Andy I tried both calling the document template and calling a batch file which executes the template, both did not work properly.

Comment: I would suggest trying the full path to Winword.exe eg: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\Winword.exe  /t"c:\path2template\template.dotm". Obviously, fix for your paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working!

I am going to post this as an answer for the unlikely case that someone has the same issue as me and stumbles across this question.

For starters, I created a batch file in the same directory as the `.dotm` file with the following command:

> start YourTemplate.dotm

Then I created a task in Windows' task scheduler.

On the tab **General**:

- Select `Run only when user is logged in`
- Check `Run with highest privileges`

On the tab **Triggers**:

- In my case, I created a weekly trigger every monday at 6 AM, nothing special here, but make sure `Enabled` is checked

On the tab **Actions**:

- Select `Start a program` in the dropdown menu on the top
- Under *program/script* enter the full path to your batch file **in quotation marks**

E.g.: `"C:\path\to\your\script.bat"`

- Under *Start in (optional)* enter the path to the location of the file **without quotation marks**

E.g.: `C:\path\to\your\`

Thanks to Shadrick's answer in [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/57c65328-d8c8-4e13-9b51-e017ae6c298c/task-scheduler-returns-0x1-code-when-run-whehter-user-is-logged-on-or-not-options-selected?forum=winserverManagement) on the Microsoft forums.

On the tab **Conditions**:

- Uncheck everything

On the tab **Settings**:

- You can probably leave everything as is

That's it, thanks to @Andy for the help provided in the comments.